# Issue with uploading files with RCURL

Tags: r, rcurl

Here, I want to attach a file to certain Policy/Claim Number with the below command in the intranet URL.

```
library(RCurl)

options(RCurlOptions = list(
  cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"),
  followlocation = TRUE, 
  httpheader = c(
    Accept = "text/xml",
    Accept = "multipart/*",'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    SOAPAction = "INTRANET URL"
  ),
  userpwd = "USERID:PASSWORD",
  netrc = TRUE,
  timeout = 100,
  postfields = CONTAINS SOAP DATA, 
  writefunction = reader$update, 
  verbose =  TRUE, 
  httpauth = AUTH_BASIC)
)

getForm(
  uri = "INTRANET URL", 
  file = fileUpload(
    filename = "C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\image001.pdf",
    contentType = "application/pdf"
  ),
  upload = TRUE
)
```

When I run the above commands, I am getting the status as "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" but the response from the service says no attachment.

```
* Couldn't find host applications.test.intra.XXXXX.nl in the _netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 11.11.11.11... * Connected to URL (11.11.11.11) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:*   CAfile: C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.2/library/RCurl/CurlSSL/cacert.pem
  CApath: none* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / ROOT* Server certificate:
*    subject: CN=applications-tst.XX.XXXXX.com*      start date: DATE TIMESTAMP GMT
*    expire date: DATE TIMESTAMP GMT*    subjectAltName: applications.test.intra.XXXXX.XX matched
*    issuer: DC=com; DC=XXXXX; DC=us; CN=XXXXX-SHA2-Issuing-us-XXXXXXXXXX-CA*    SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'USERID'
> POST /QUALIFIER1/QUALIFIER2/QUALIFIER3?file=C%3A%5CUsers%5CUSERNAME%5CDesktop%5Cimage001.pdf&file=character%280%29&file=application%2Fpdf&upload=TRUE HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX= Host: applications.test.intra.XXXXX.nl
Accept: text/xml Accept: multipart/* Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: https://applications.test.intra.XXXXX.nl/QUALIFIER1/QUALIFIER2/QUALIFIER3 Content-Length: 2654 Expect: 100-continue

* Done waiting for 100-continue < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < content-language: en-GB
< content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 < date: Fri, 24 Nov 2017 11:33:00 GMT < p3p: CP="XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX"
< transfer-encoding: chunked < cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2" < expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
< x-powered-by: Servlet/3.0 < Set-Cookie: LtpaToken2=TOKEN; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly 
< Set-Cookie: BIGipServer~XX~isam-emp-applications_tst_11111=111111111.11111.1111; path=/; Httponly; Secure
< * Connection #0 to host applications.test.intra.XXXXX.nl left intact
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I realize you can't easily post the output you saw with the `verbose` flag set due to this being an internal resource, but, you should have seen indications there of an attachment. If you can strip the verbose output of IP addresses, host names and any other "sensitive" data (replace with `X`'s or something like that) it'd be easier to know what might be happening. SOAP requests can be tricky.

Comment: Hi hrbrmstr, Thanks for the reply, Could you please let me know about how can i achieve this, This will be of great help please, Thanks

Comment: You have `verbose` in the example code. That means you had a ton of console output. Select, copy & past that into a text editor. Find IP addresses, usernames (etc) and then X them out and then select, cut & paste the output into your question. I can help format it but prefixing lines with 4 spaces makes it appear like what you see now.

Comment: (it's better form to modify the question than to use comments for this, please do that)

Comment: Hi hrbrmstr, As suggested I have added the verbose output by making X's the host names, IP address and some other

Comment: As suggested, I have added in the question itself. Please suggest

Comment: Hi  hrbrmstr, Could you please suggest on the above question, Thanks